# Google Search Engine in AddressBar of Android Application

Tags: android, browser, google-search

Is possible to use the "Google" Search Engine, with tips in my Browser Application in Android? I'm developing a browser, that search for contents in an EditText (used as addressbar), but only by an URL instead of a word. Is possible to make this, detecting when user is searching for an url?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by coding this:

public static final String SEARCH_ENGINE_GOOGLE     = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";

```
    mUrlView.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //   submit_btn.performClick();

                if (mUrlView.getText().toString().contains("http://")) {
                    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrlView.getText().toString());
                } else if (mUrlView.getText().toString().contains(".")) {


                    mWebView.loadUrl("http://" + mUrlView.getText().toString());


                } else {
                    mWebView.loadUrl(SEARCH_ENGINE_GOOGLE + mUrlView.getText().toString());

                }

                return true;


            } else {
                mWebView.loadUrl(mUrlView.getText().toString());

                return false;
            }
        }
    });


    return v;


}
```

By adding the Google search prefix if the text in the TextBox doesn't contains any dot or http://

Answer (score 1):

you can get the user input from the edit text and check if it starts with https,http,www etc and ends with com,in,org etc.Then you can know if the user is searching for word or entering url

Comment: It's a rough solution. It's impossible to detect every prefix, but if I would do that, I still have the problem of the "Google Search"